# CSS-only show hidden div, hide the "show" link upon showing the hidden div

Tags: html, css

I've seen many CSS3 examples of doing a show/hide, but I don't want to be able to hide the hidden div again, just need a "show" link, that upon being clicked, shows the hidden div and hides the "show" link. I've seen some good hacks done with input buttons, how can I do this specific method of showing hidden content?

Comment: Not possible without js...

Comment: imput + label + div and pseudo class :checked does the trick

Comment: @Mooseman That's wrong. It is possible with some clever CSS.

Comment: :focus(+ tabindex)  or :target(+id) could be used too :)

Comment: Because you displayed no effort at attempting a solution it seems your question was closed as 'off-topic,' before asking another question please try to understand and appreciate those reasons, and ask on [meta] if there's something you don't understand about the restrictions. I do, though, think you deserve a useful answer (current answers don't address your 'show only' requirement) and I enjoyed playing with this. So, hopefully it's useful: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/zbYuS/1/). But please, learn to ask better questions that don't rely on someone's terrible idea of 'fun'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented earlier with help from `input` and `:checked` pseudo-class, for younger browser : **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/nKgew)**

HTML basis

```
<div>
  <input id="hidiv" type="checkbox" value=""/> 
  <label for="hidiv" > Show more </label>
  <div class="toshow">div to show </div>
</div>
```

CSS basis

```
#hidiv {
  position:absolute;
  left:-9999px;
}
label  {/* for demo , style with link defaut style */
    display:inline-block;
  color:blue;
  text-decoration:underline;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.toshow ,
#hidiv:checked + label {
  display:none; /* once input checked, you cannot checked it anymore via the click */
}
#hidiv:checked ~ .toshow {
  display:block;
}
```

You can have many boxes  with each its own input and label.

Comment: This is excellent, and works for me! Is there any reason I can't use #hidiv {
  display:none;
} or does that break it in older browsers?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is using the `:target` pseudo selector, very [very] simple example:

```
<style>
    #state_b { display: none; }
    #state_b:target { display: block; }
    #state_b:target + a { display: none; }
</style>
<div id=state_b>hello world</div>
<a href=#state_b>show</a>
```

You can use this technique to change states, however you wouldn't be able to have multiple boxes like this on the same page.

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/sPW9V/)